# Rails 7 - Rails considering DELETE action as GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Operations model and I am trying to delete a record using the delete method. But I am getting a **Routing error**. I cannot understand why Rails is considering Delete action as Get. Below is the error message.

**Error:**
`No route matches [GET] "/home/delete_operation/1"`

Below is the logic what I have setup.

**View:**

```
<%= link_to 'Delete operation', home_delete_operation_path(id: operation.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?', turbo: false }, class: "btn btn-dark btn-sm rounded-0" %>
```

**Controller:**

```
def delete_operation
    @operation = Operation.find(params[:id])
    @operation.destroy
  end
```

**Routes:**

```
delete 'home/delete_operation/:id', to: 'home#delete_operation', as: :home_delete_operation
```

I read Rails uses JS for Routing. Therefore, attaching the code in Applicaion.js

**Application.js**

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chartkick
//= require Chart.bundle
import "chartkick"
import "Chart.bundle"
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the jQuery ujs is loaded correctly? Do you see the alert on click?

Comment: @David No I don’t see the alert. Straightaway when I click the Delete button on the view, I get this error.

Comment: can you verify that it's updated to the latest version and loads correctly (in the browser's inspection tool)?

Comment: rails 7: `data: {turbo_method: :delete}`.  `//= require` directives only work at the top, above any code. but just pin your packages and switch to @import.

Comment: @Alex Can you elaborate it in simpler words ? I am new to Rails and it difficult for me to follow your comment. Thanks

Comment: Why do you decide to use jquery_ujs? It is library that was removed after rails 4

Answer (score 2):

Replaced existing `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?', turbo: false }`  with this `data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' }` in the link_to tag and it worked.

Comment: looks like you've figured it out) Hard to say it any simpler without explaining how every bit works, but here are some references. Turbo is new js framework, which replaced ujs: https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes, sprockets directives is a bit of an outdated way, put them above the imports: https://github.com/rails/sprockets#directives, but rails uses import-maps by default and the way to use them is to pin the packages then import them: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails#using-npm-packages-via-javascript-cdns